# T-SQL select statement to redistribute value in row into n rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table like (SQL Server 2016):

```
    ID    Month      Sales
    1     Jan 2019   40
    2     Feb 2019   80
    3     Mar 2019   400

...
```

would like to get sales redistributed by weeks (here we can assume each month is 4 weeks) like:

```
ID    Month      Sales
1     012019     10
1     022019     10
1     032019     10
1     042019     10
2     052019     20
2     062019     20
2     072019     20
2     082019     20
3     092019     100
3     102019     100
3     112019     100
3     122019     100
...
```

How can I achieve sth like that?

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: tried to loop thorough each record so replace i.e Jan with @i+1 and divide Sales by 4 and insert it in another table but need it in a single select statement

Comment: I don't see a query.

Comment: The problem is not with the query I've written but need to figure out how to get same results with a single select statement (not looping through each record)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join the query with a hard-coded query that generates four rows:

```sql
SELECT     id, month, sales / 4
FROM       mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS col 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 3
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 4) t
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Saw and used this construction multiple times but couldn't remember now. Thank's a lot.